# Fillable PDF form with button to upload completed PDF to web server

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I'm trying to find a way to host some fillable PDF forms on our website that people can download, fill out, and then they have a SUBMIT button on it that would 1) upload the completed form to a folder on our web server as a PDF file, and then ideally 2) email a direct link to the file on the server.  I know how to add the button, just not clear on the actions side for this scenario.

Adobe docs have some info here, https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/publishing-interactive-pdf-web-forms.html, but nothing specific to what I need.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  And if it's even a realistic goal given the number of different PDF readers, browser-based viewers, etc and how it would be supported by all?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my understanding, step 2 has to be implemented on the server; you might have to set up the receiving folder as watched, and determine the uploader's eMail address either via login information, or via another way.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback!